# How to embed user names in word2vec model in gensim

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec

I have some volunteer essay writings in the format of:

```
volunteer_names, essay
["emi", "jenne", "john"], [["lets", "protect", "nature"], ["what", "is", "nature"], ["nature", "humans", "earth"]]
["jenne", "li"], [["lets", "manage", "waste"]]
["emi", "li", "jim"], [["python", "is", "cool"]]
...
...
...
```

I want to identify the similar users based on their essay writings. I feel like word2vec is more suitable in problems like this. However, since I want to embed user names too in the model I am not sure how to do it. The examples I found in the internet only uses the words (See example code).

```
import gensim 
sentences = [['first', 'sentence'], ['second', 'sentence']]
# train word2vec on the two sentences
model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(sentences, min_count=1)
```

In that case, I am wondering if there is special way of doing this in word2vec or can I simply consider user names as just words to input to the model. please let me know your thoughts on this.

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Word2vec infers the word representation from surrounding words: words similarly often appear in a similar company end up with similar vectors. Usually, a window of 5 words is considered. So, if you want to hack Word2vec, you would need to make sure that the student names will appear frequently enough (perhaps at a beginning and at the end of a sentence or something like that).

Alternatively, you can have a look at Doc2vec. During training, each document gets an ID and learns an embedding for the ID, they are in a lookup table as if they were word embeddings. If you use student names as document IDs, you would get student embeddings. If you have multiple essays from one student, I suppose you would need to hack Gensim a little bit not to have a unique ID for each essay.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I had the idea of doc2vec before. However, most of the essay are written by multiple users (not just a single user). So, I was thinking that doc2vec may not provide much insights as it represents embedding of the every user who contribute to write it. Since, my focus is more towards capturing single user behaviour, I thought that word2vec would be better. Please correct me if I am wrong :)

Comment: In that case yes. Or you can still rewrite the doc2vec code to work with multiple IDs https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/models/doc2vec.py

Comment: The gensim `Doc2Vec` implementation already allows each text to have multiple document-tags – so you can label each essay with all of the author names, and still get a vector per author. And, with suitable training data, similar authors will likely wind up with nearby vectors.